# AWS S3 bucket - 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, post, amazon-s3

I uploaded my react and express SPA to an s3 bucket. I have a server route mapped to `/mail` and and form that triggers a post request to the server route. However I am getting the following error:

> Request URL: http://www.example.com/mail
>
> Request Method: POST
>
> Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed

Does anybody know to solve this issue? Or is it possible to achieve this only with an s3 bucket or would I have to use a lambda fucntion for the server route?